# Connection speed problem

Tags: directory, speed

There is an odd problem with my connection speed that i want to know what is causing that .
In my country as many other countries TOR is illegal also filtered and i was connecting through bridges but there is a problem in speed in certain time periods.
Simply in my country with UTC +3:30 time offset from 8 to 12 pm for about like 5 months whenever i want to connect to any bridges it takes time and speed is very awful at those moments but after 1 or 2 pm speed gets back to normal . I am wondering what causing this ?
Can you help me about this ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried other bridges? And does your non-tor internet become slower around this time as well?

Comment: Yes i've tried so many bridges that in some point i almost lost an hour trying to even see a youtube page and also yes i tested my non tor net connection and it worked perfectly during that time . Both Download and Upload speed were fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's slow, but it might just be that the entire network is slow during those times. For example, see the CPU usage graphs for an exit relay, where the usage cycles with a period of 24 hours (although this graph actually seems to show the opposite effect of what you're describing): http://185.220.100.253/system-cpu.html

Comment: I saw the graphs and they look normal to me as well but even so i test the connection with cellular internet of my phone(3G+4G) to connect to TOR in my laptop exactly same time periods and the results were same , again...Funny thing , I was asking around some of my friends and colleagues  and they were experiencing the same problem and it seems i'm the only one who cares about this . I'm starting to think that TOR network doesn't like us anymore :) but aside all the jokes isn't it a bit suspicious?Maybe i'm overthinking or else but thanks anyway for your helpful answers